# `include ActiveModel::Model` with class name having more than two words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel

It seems I am missing the magic of ruby on rails 4.
I wanted to create an object which includes `ActiveModel::Model` but which class name contains two words.

Therefore I created `app/models/registration_form.rb` with the following code:

```
class RegistrationForm
    include ActiveModel::Model
    attr_accessor(:email)
    validates :email, presence: true
end
```

When the object is created within the controller by using `RegistrationForm.new` the following error occurs:

```
Could not find table 'registration_forms'
```

When I just delete the postfix `Form` and rename the file to `app/models/registration.rb` everthing works fine.

When the code from above is executed within `rails console` everything works fine, too.

The stacktrace of the error shows that ActiveRecord is called:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/273986937cd774b5953c

Comment: Are you using `ActiveModel` or `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: wrap it in module and access it like `Registration::Form`

Comment: ActiveModel, I don't know why ActiveRecord is called. Which is the best way to debug this?

Comment: Does this model have a database table? If not, are you sure you don't just want to include parts of ActiveModel, e.g. ActiveModel::Validations?

Comment: Does your app contain another RegistrationForm class that does subclass from active record?

Comment: it was a name collision which has driven me mad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to initialise an ActiveRecord object in your parties controller. It may simply be a name collision. Do you have another file defining RegistrationForm as a regular ActiveRecord model?